why there is one same color for all linerenderers?
// Initialize and set up the LineRenderers for the eyes and finger
leftEyeLineRenderer = eyeLeft.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
rightEyeLineRenderer = eyeRight.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
fingerLineRenderer = finger.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

SetUpLineRenderer(leftEyeLineRenderer, Color.yellow);
SetUpLineRenderer(rightEyeLineRenderer, Color.yellow);
SetUpLineRenderer(fingerLineRenderer, Color.blue);

and
private void SetUpLineRenderer(LineRenderer lineRenderer, Color color)
{
    // Create a simple unlit material that supports vertex colors
    Material lineMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
    lineRenderer.material = lineMaterial;

    lineRenderer.startColor = color;
    lineRenderer.endColor = color;
    lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.01f;
    lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.01f;
}

but the result is that all the linerenderers have the same color.  and i'm not sure if that even yellow but i want that two will have yellow and one blue.


solution is to use Sprites/Default
instead:
Material lineMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));

change it to:
Material lineMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));

i also tried "Unlit/Color" but for now the only one that work is "Sprites/Default".

yes, or basically any shader supporting vertex colors! ;)
